# Default gateway is 192.168.1.1 but can't access it with browser

Tags: home-networking, modem

I have a Zyxel P-870H VDSL modem, I"M trying to diagnose internet problems.

I have my computer computer plugged into it via ethernet. I'm able to access the internet, and ipconfig tells me that the default gateway is 192.168.1.1, and I'm able to ping that address,  but when I enter that into the browser, I'm not able to access the modem.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you ping the default gateway from command prompt with: ping 192.168.1.1 what response you receive?

Comment: This question should've been just edits from your original question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/821890/192-168-1-1-randomly-switching-between-accessing-vdsl-modem-and-accessing-the-w).

Answer (score 0):

first check if that is actually the IP for the default gateway by going into cmd then type

```
ipconfig /all
```

It will be listed there.

If that is fine then simply check if you are connected properly and then try restarting the modem.

Answer (score 0):

First, try "Telnet 192.168.1.1 80" to see if the Modem really offers an web admin interface with the standard HTTP port. Under Windows 7, you may need to install Telnet client.

If the port is open, try to disable all proxy settings in your browser. In this way you will not be borthered with trying to access the Modem through a proxy Server.