# Wireless router setup, two default gateways, unable to access internet

Tags: home-networking

I have a basic wireless router setup.

I have a Zxyel P-870H  VDSL modem plugged into the wall, an ethernet cable from there to a TP-LINK TD-W8960n Wireless router.

Ipconfig shows 192.168.1.1 (the modem) and 192.168.1.2 (the router) as the default gateways.

I'm able to access each of the the router and the modem through the browser, however I'm unable to access the internet. However, other devices such as my phone, are able to access the internet.  I'm able to access the internet if I plug via ethernet into the modem.

DCHP is disabled on the router, and is enabled on the modem. NAT is enabled on the modem.

Any ideas how I begin to understand what's happening?

Comment: When you're connected to wireless only, try "tracert 192.168.1.1" in a cmd prompt.  You might need to logon to the wireless router and specify 192.168.1.1 as *its* default gateway.

Comment: @Steve - Tracert provided no response. The router says `Default Gateway: 0.0.0.0 (pppoa0)`

Comment: `Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

1     1 ms     1 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1`

Comment: This question, along with [this](http://superuser.com/questions/822955/default-gateway-is-192-168-1-1-but-cant-access-it-with-browser) one, should've been just edits from your original question [here](http://superuser.com/questions/821890/192-168-1-1-randomly-switching-between-accessing-vdsl-modem-and-accessing-the-w).

Comment: @happy_soil They all cover different questions, and are the results of different configurations.

Comment: I've corrected a mistake in my answer, changing "default router" to "default gateway".

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the notes above, you need to set the default gateway on your wireless router, so the devices attached to the wireless router know how to move upstream onto the Internet.

Comment: are you accidently a word here? 'set the default router on your wireless router'? What setting needs configuring?